# Ember: Error with named outlets

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I do not know why my templates are not being rendered in the named outlets.  This is my first stab at learning ember and I am stuck on the named outlets.

I would like to render the **sidebarTemplate** in the `{{outlet "sidebar"}}` and the **contentTemplate** in the `{{outlet "content"}}` but I keep getting the following error in the console: "Error while processing route: posts Cannot read property 'connectOutlet' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectOutlet' of undefined"

Here is a fiddle to my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/va71wwr9/

Here is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>{{#link-to 'home'}}Home{{/link-to}}</li>
        <li>{{#link-to 'posts'}}Posts{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="home">
  <h1>Home screen</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
  <h1>Posts screen</h1>
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    {{outlet sidebar}}
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    {{outlet content}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="sidebarTemplate">
  <p>Side bar stuff</p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="contentTemplate">
  <p>content stuff</p>
</script>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('home', {path: '/'});
  this.resource('home', {path: 'home'});
  this.resource('posts', {path: 'posts'});
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('sidebarTemplate', {
        into: 'posts',
        outlet: 'sidebar'
    });
    this.render('contentTemplate', {
        into: 'posts',
        outlet: 'content'
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not rendering the `posts` template. You can fix this by adding `this.render()` or `this._super()` before you define the templates of the outlets of the route you are in get rendered:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {

        // add this line
        this._super();

        this.render('sidebarTemplate', {
            into: 'posts',
            outlet: 'sidebar'
        });
        this.render('contentTemplate', {
            into: 'posts',
            outlet: 'content'
        });
    }
});
```

Just one note on extending features; In this particular code, the call `this._super()` would *technically* be the same as calling `this.render()`, but the difference is that by calling `_super()` you are extending the `renderTemplate` functionality by appending your stuff to what the method would do on its own, which in this case would be call `this.render()` and perhaps another routine this method might need to perform (generally speaking, not exclusive to `renderTemplate`), while if you call the method that does the thing you want yourself, in this case the `render` method, you'll be excluding from the flow the other things that this method *could* perform. And this is not right or wrong. It really depends on what you want to achieve. For most cases you should call `this._super()` instead of re-writing the implementation again in the event that the method you're extending does more than one thing and/or gets to do more than one thing in the future.

Comment: Thank you!!!!  I was following the Ember documentation for rendering a template and I see they are also not calling `this.render()`.  Is there a better way for me to structure my code?  Here's the documentation page I was referencing:  http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Comment: Keep in mind that the documentation doesn't include all possible scenarios. I've edited my answer to explain a little more. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you again!  I've been really impressed by what I've seen from Ember, but am just now trying to work with it.  I wish I could give you more up-votes.